# User in Unix not able to run hadoop command

Tags: unix, hadoop, installation

I installed Hadoop and Created a user named hduser and changes owner of hadoop folder to hduser.

After installing Hadoop i try to execute the hadoop command to check whether it is installed or not but it is giving "hadoop" command not found.

Then i had given execute privilege to hduser on all the files inside hadoop folder include bin folder
But still output is same.

When i am trying the same hadoop command with root as a user its working fine.

I think it is related to unix commands. Please help me out to give my user the privilege to execute hadoop command.

**One more thing if i switch to root then hadoop commands works fine.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a problem of privileges. You can still execute hadoop, if you type `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop`, right?

The problem is that `$PATH` is user-specific. 
You have to add your `$HADOOP_HOME/bin` to the `$PATH`, as hduser, not as root. Login as hduser first (or just type `su hduser`) and then `export PATH=$PATH:/$HADOOP_HOME/bin`, as @iamkristian suggests, where $HADOOP_HOME is the directory in which you have placed hadoop (usually `/usr/local/hadoop`).

Comment: Thanks a lot this is actually what i want to know.

Answer (score 2):

I sounds like hadoop isn't in your path. You can test that with

```
which hadoop
```

If that gives you `command not found` the you probably just need to add it to your path. Depending on where you installed hadoop, you need to add this to your `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/hadoop/bin/
```

And then reopen your terminal

Comment: I had already set it and it showing it in which command. The problem is that with root as a user its showing it but when i switch to hduser it's not showing the path.

Comment: And you added the above to the .bashrc of hduser?